# remove new arraylist evertime Web-service calls

Tags: android, arraylist, removeall

- I am having 3 arraylist, 1st arraylist contains default value
- 2nd arraylist contains values from web-service
- I am comparing 2 arraylist values, and getting un-common value from two list and fill 3rd arraylist with un-common list.
- But my problem is that , everytime web-service is calling, list is filling again and again.
- code :

  ```
              arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();   

              for (int i = 0; i < arrayListNew.size(); i++) {

                  idNew = arrayListNew.get(i).get("id");

                  if(idNew.contains(arraylist.get(i).get("id")))
                  {
                      newAlert = true;
                      return;

                  }else {
                      NewList = new HashMap<String, String>();

                      NewList.put("id", idNew);

                      arraylist1.add(NewList);

                      arraylist.addAll(arraylist1);

                      listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);

                      lvTitle.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                      listAdapter.show(i);

                      generateNotification();

                  }

                  arraylist1.clear();

              }
  ```
- can anyone suggest me where should i clear arraylist i.e. **arraylist1** everytime or remove previous values

Comment: where should is clear that ?

Comment: i know how to clear, but where to clear ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit messy but I think I saw your problem. You are checking only one position of the arrayList instead of check all the arrayList. I think this could be the correct solution, even though maybe I didn't understand well your problem:

```
newAlert = false

for (int j=0; i < arrayListNew.size(); i++) ){

    if(!idNew.contains(arraylist.get(i).get("id")))
                {
                    newAlert = true;
                    return;
                }


}

if(newAlert){

NewList = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    NewList.put("id", idNew);



                    arraylist1.add(NewList);


                    arraylist.addAll(arraylist1);

                    listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);

                    lvTitle.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                    listAdapter.show(i);

                    generateNotification();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try it..Clear your list before for loop

 arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       arraylist1.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayListNew.size(); i++) {

                    idNew = arrayListNew.get(i).get("id");

                    if(idNew.contains(arraylist.get(i).get("id")))
                    {
                        newAlert = true;
                        return;

                    }else {
                        NewList = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        NewList.put("id", idNew);

                        arraylist1.add(NewList);

                        arraylist.addAll(arraylist1);

                        listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);

                        lvTitle.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                        listAdapter.show(i);

                        generateNotification();

                    }



                }
```